# Spring Boot Microsoft AD Authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory

I know little about Spring Boot and even less about Active Directory.

I need to Authenticate against Microsoft Active Directory using Spring Boot and JWT. I have working JWT with user from memory but i am having trouble authenticating against user from Microsoft AD.

Microsoft AD setup:

- Active Directory is running on Windows Server 2012r2 (192.168.1.166).
- [AD users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjPiJ.png)
- [AD user property.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3E9l.png)

Spring Boot app is running on: 192.168.1.31:8082
Spring Boot config:

```
import com.mts.oh.config.cors.SimpleCORSFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleCORSFilter myCorsFilter;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(myCorsFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class).
                csrf().disable().
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).
                and().
                authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login").permitAll().
                anyRequest().authenticated().
                and().
                addFilterBefore(new LoginInterceptor("/api/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).
                addFilterBefore(new JwtInterceptor(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("bmad.com",
            "ldap://192.168.1.166:389/DC=bmad,DC=com");
    provider.setSearchFilter("OU=devs,OU=employees");
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        return provider;
    }
}
```

Login endpoint is: /api/login.
Postman request:

- [Login Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTnwx.png)
- [Login Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7rLw.png)

Stack Trace:

```
> rg.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:
> Bad credentials
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:295)
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:300)
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.raiseExceptionForErrorCode(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:267)
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.handleBindException(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:233)
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
>       at com.mts.oh.config.security.LoginInterceptor.attemptAuthentication(LoginInterceptor.java:28)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at com.mts.oh.config.cors.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:32)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at com.mts.oh.config.cors.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:32)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>     Caused by: org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException:
> [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment:
> AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, v2580 ]
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.raiseExceptionForErrorCode(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:250)
>       ... 61 common frames omitted
>     Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext
> error, data 773, v2580 ]
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3154)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2886)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2800)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
>       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
>       at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider$ContextFactory.createContext(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:402)
>       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.bindAsUser(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:203)
>       ... 59 common frames omitted
```

I have tried different combinations of username and password but none of them work:

- John Doe / ****
- johnupn / ****
- johnupn@bmad.com / ****
- bmad\johnupn / ****

I have picked up Spring Boot configuration from:
https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-active-directory-authentication-5ea04969f220
and
https://www.ziaconsulting.com/developer-help/spring-security-active-directory/
but these do not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

From a computer logged into the domain, a user can find the values for their account using [whoami](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/whoami). Below shows the commands to get a user's sAMAccountName, userPrincipalName, and fully qualified distinguished name respectively. Active Directory uses all three of these as the username when authenticating via LDAP.

```
c:>whoami
mydomain\lisa

c:>whoami /upn
lisa@mydomain.ccTLD

c:>whoami /fqdn
CN=Smith\, Lisa,OU=GPOTest,OU=IT,OU=Company,DC=mydomain,DC=ccTLD
```

Comment: How does your answer help?

Comment: My answer helps because multiple iterations of the user id were being attempted. Two of the four iterations are not valid, and the other two may or may not be valid depending on the actual values used within AD. I've seen domains where example.com still has OldComp as their sAMAccountName prefix and sometimes an internal DNS like Company.Local in their userPrincipalName. There is nothing to be gained by continuing to test and troubleshoot using invalid user IDs. Knowing exactly what needs to be used as the user ID eliminates a cause of failure that absolutely will yield LDAP err 49.